How to embedd a pdf document on your react native for users to download
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Button, View, Text, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
const downloadPdf = () => {
const source = { uri: '/Users/buhleradzilani/Desktop/The IIE Harvard Style Reference Guide – Adapted for The IIE 2023.pdf', cache: true };


return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pdf
            source={source}
            onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath) => {
                console.log(`Number of fdd pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
            }}
            onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages) => {
                console.log(`Current page: ${page}`);
            }}
            onError={(error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }}
            onPressLink={(uri) => {
                console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
            }}
            style={styles.pdf}/>
    </View>
)

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 25,
},
pdf: {
flex:1,
width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
height:Dimensions.get('window').height,
}
});
export default downloadPdf
I am getting an error saying cannot react property 'DocumentDir' of null
